# Copying and pasting emoji in a wordpress post

Tags: posts, images, css

There's this site that allows to copy and paste emoji's https://getemoji.com/

If I copy and paste from there into my posts will it work everywhere?

Is it something like Font awesome? To use them I have to include the font and css files.

How does it work in case of emojis? Where are they "defined"?

Comment: Copied  from mentioned site and posted at [here](http://attocknet.com/happy-pakistan-day/) and it worked. It will render everywhere if visitor OS support Emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emoji are just letters. They're defined by the user's operating system. The same way the alphabet is. You don't need to do anything special. If you did, then that website would be pointless.

The only thing you need to consider is older operating systems that don't support Emoji, but WordPress itself loads a script that enables Emoji for those operating systems.

Comment: Thanks! What would happen in the case of Older OS. Would it display some missing character?

Comment: @nshunz see the last paragraph of the answer, WP loads a script that enables emoji for those operating systems

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks! What does the script do? Does it display an error or a message if the emoji doesn't display?

Comment: It does not display an error or a message, if it did it wouldn't enable emoji, which wouldn't make it a good emoji enabling script. Like the answer says, it enables support for emoji on browsers that don't have emoji support. Perhaps this would be better as a full question?